# Why cant i use base constructor in c#

Tags: c#, constructor, derived-class

let's say we have two classes

```
class baseClass
{
    public baseClass()
    {

    }
    public baseClass(int value)
    {

    }
}

class derivedClass
{

}
```

is there a way to call the parametrized constructor from `derivedClass` like

```
derivedClass instance = new derivedClass(1)
```

without implmenting a constructor in `derivedClass` which cals `base(value)`

Comment: "...without implmenting a constructor in derivedClass..." No. In order to pass arguments to a constructor you need to make a constructor.

Comment: If there was an auto-passthrough of those parameters,  then you would need special syntax to *prevent* that when you don't want it.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for something along the lines of

```
   class BaseClass
   {
      public BaseClass()
      {

      }
      public BaseClass(int value)
      {

      }
   }

   class DerivedClass : BaseClass
   {
      public DerivedClass(int value) : base(value)
      {

      }
   }
```

Which allows you to call :

```
DerivedClass test = new DerivedClass(2);
```

Comment: i know this kind of solution but i wonder if there is any solution where i do not need this part :
```public DerivedClass(int value) : base(value) { }``` in any derived class

Comment: @NeoPrince No, you have to define constructors you want in the child class to propagate what you want. Take a look for example at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-inheritance-in-constructors/ and [C# MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp)

Comment: OP said, `without implmenting a constructor in derivedClass`... this is the exact opposite.

Comment: Unless you call the base(value) inside of one of your derived constructors, I don't think you can. The BaseClass constructor can't define the DerivedClass instance.